# Actions must be plain objects, even though it seems my actions are already plain

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I am developing an app with React Native and Redux. I have some authentication and localisation logic handled by Redux, and now I want to fetch needed data from remote API using Redux as well.

An example of what I had for authentication:

```
actions.auth.js

export function saveAuthToken(authToken) {
    return {
        type: "SAVE_AUTH_TOKEN",
        authToken
    };
}
...
```

```
reducers.auth.js

export function authToken(state = "", action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SAVE_AUTH_TOKEN":
            return action.authToken;
        ...
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

What I am now trying to add:

```
actions.data.js

export function fetchData() {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_DATA"
    };
}
...
```

```
reducers.data.js

export function dataList(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_DATA":
            return {};
        ...
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

For test purposes, I now don't even make any calls to API. Just try to return `{}` for data in any case.

Even though I think that I made everything identical to the way I handled authentication (which worked), when I try to call:
`store.dispatch('FETCH_DATA');`
I get the following error:

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

I don't quite get where exactly I try to use async actions and why my actions aren't plain objects.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[store.dispatch()](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) takes an `action` as an argument.
And, as the error says, the `action` must be plain object.

The error is obvious, because
what you are passing to `dispatch()` is a `string` and not an `object`.

Here is what you would want to do:

```
import { fetchData } from '<file-path-here>'

store.dispatch(fetchData())
```

You see, the `fetchData()` would then return a plain object which is required by `store.dispatch()`

Comment: Yes, thank you! Another option is to write `store.dispatch({type: 'FETCH_DATA'});`

Comment: Yes! You can directly pass the `action` object or call the `actionCreator` function. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
reducers.data.js

export function dataList(state = {}, action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_DATA":
        return {...state};
    ...
    default:
        return state
}
}

export function fetchData() { return dispatch{ type: "FETCH_DATA" }; }
```

use dispatch to dispatch your actions

Comment: A reducer must  return an object (state) which shouldn't  mutate the original set of data thus used as {...state, //override data as data:newValue} .

Comment: export function fetchData() {
    return dispatch{
        type: "FETCH_DATA"
    };
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any custom middleware then your action must be plain object in your case like below

```
store.dispatch({
  type : 'FETCH_DATA',
  payload : {} // if any pass here
})
```

You can not dispatch action as string it must have a plain object like 
   `{
      type: 'YOUR_ACTION',
      payload: yourPayload
    }` 
if you want to pass function or else you must use custom middleware it will also use to dispatch function you can use `thunk` as middleware or `redux-saga`.

This link will help you.

[redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)
[redux-saga](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-saga)

It will help you.